Euclidean $D$-dimensional Klein-Gordon equation in QFT
I have seen many times that in the Euclidean space the massive Green’s function satisfies the equation
$$(\nabla_x^2-m^2)G(x,y)=-\delta^D(x-y) \tag{1}$$
but in Minkowski space-time it satisfies
$$(\partial_t^2-\nabla^2+m^2)G(x,y)=\delta^D(x-y).\tag{2}$$
How is the Euclidean equation (1) derived from (2)? By doing the Wick rotation it doesn't seems that it gets to the same equation as the first one.

Hint: Remember that $x^0=ct$ with $c=1$.


So it's only doing the wick rotation of t-> i\tau ?
If it is, doesn't the mass needs to change it's sign?



Up to a sign. 2. Mass $m$ is unchanged.

